# How to merge similar items in a list in dart programming?

Tags: string, algorithm, list, flutter, dart

How to merge similar item in a list in dart programming language?

I have list like this:

```
[A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, D0, D1, D2, D3, D4]
```

And i want list like this:

```
[A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, D0, D1, D2, D3, D4]
```

How this can be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can initialize a `Set` from the given `List` and cast it back again to `List`:

```dart
List myList = [A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, D0, D1, D2, D3, D4];

List ouput = Set.of(myList).toList(); // removes duplicates
```